# Rails: ActiveRecord is not parsing time correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm assigning a time value in model with

`self.started_at = Time.now`

When I save it, I get following:

```
   Created at: 2012-05-05 12:11:54 +0200 
   Started at: 2000-01-01 10:12:06 UTC
```

I've tried formatting with `Time.now.to_s(:db)` but the result is the same. Does this depend on locale settings? (I have `activerecord 3.1.3`)

Comment: which db?do you have both as datetime field or string in db?

Comment: it's PostgreSQL, the type is `t.time`. I'll check how it's stored in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to go with `t.datetime` which stores date n time part... whereas `time` doesn't...[see time range for mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html)

Comment: sure, in PostreSQL it's quite similar. I was probably too lazy to look up some migration manual for data types. here's a good cheat list: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/migrations/

Comment: nice cheat sheet... :) ... i always have to google up whenever i write a migration for syntax/type etc..